Unable to open Port 19132 on oracle cloud instance running Ubuntu + Wireguard
I have been trying to run an mc bedrock server on my computer for the last couple of weeks for me and my friends and I'm behind CGnat so port forwarding is out of the question. I have an Ubuntu instance running Wireguard I just watched a YouTube tutorial with some but limited knowledge of Linux to get me through I have my ingress rules set correctly and just repeated what I did for Wireguard which works fine. When I use a port checker tool it says it's closed I'm stumped and have no idea what I'm doing haha I'd appreciate any tips.
wg0.conf
[Interface]
Address = 10.16.0.1/32
ListenPort = 51820
PrivateKey = SNIP

PreUp = sysctl -w net.ipv4.ip_forward=1

PostUp = iptables -I INPUT -p udp --dport 51820 -j ACCEPT; iptables -t nat -I POSTROUTING 1 -s 10.16.0.0/24 -o ens3 -j MASQUERADE; iptables -I INPUT 1 -i wg0 -j ACCEPT; iptables -I FORWARD 1 -i ens3 -o wg0 -j ACCEPT; iptables -I FORWARD -i wg0 -o ens3 -j ACCEPT; iptables -I INPUT -p udp --dport 19132 -j ACCEPT

PostDown = iptables -D INPUT -p udp --dport 51820 -j ACCEPT; iptables -t nat -D POSTROUTING 1 -s 10.16.0.0/24 -o ens3 -j MASQUERADE; iptables -D INPUT 1 -i wg0 -j ACCEPT; iptables -D FORWARD 1 -i ens3 -o wg0 -j ACCEPT; iptables -D FORWARD -i wg0 -o ens3 -j ACCEPT; iptables -D INPUT -p udp --dport 19132 -j ACCEPT

[Peer]
PublicKey = TKBvwsMZ//QyYowXfoRh87yAy/huoLmzb4n2Cjw722Y=
AllowedIPs = 10.16.0.2/32


Oracle Cloud has its own separate firewall in front of the systems.  You need to ask Oracle Cloud how to configure that (it's probably in a 'firewall' or 'security group' section in their cloud panel)

Also, regenerate your Wireguard private key.  You just made your Wireguard installation wholly insecure by sharing that.

Thanks for the tips ill look into it. It's a free instance with a password so to me it doesn't matter but you are probably right I'll change it now

@ThomasWard Yeah I've looked under similar sections to no avail why can my Wireguard 51820 port be open but not my 19132?

considering your Wireguard is set to listen on 51820 and not 19132 that's probably a factor.  You have to change your listen port in the configuration.

@ThomasWard I don't think its that becuase port 51820 cant even be pinged as well as 19132 from the port checker tool I'm using only port 22 can be pinged

That goes to firewall (usually ping is blocked to shield your system), and because you've indicated you're on Oracle Cloud, you may need to talk to Oracle Cloud to see if you're missing something on their end to open the ports in that system to permit access.  Most cloud providers have security shields that way, but they name it different things and have different setup requirements.  I would reach out to Oracle Cloud next
